# Should I use preposition 'IN' in these sentences?

Tags: prepositions

Sentences:

> 1) I've already had three coffee **IN** this morning
>
> 2) I already had three coffee **IN** previous morning
>
> 3) I already had three coffee **IN** last morning

Question:

> Should I use the preposition 'IN' in these sentences OR it's incorrect OR optional?

Answer (score 1):

**This/last/next morning** is like **tomorrow**, **yesterday**, **next week**, **last month**. The **in** isn't required.

1. I've already had three cups of coffee this morning. (**Correct**)

Notice the change from "three coffee" to "three cups of coffee".

2. I already had three cups of coffee previous morning (*Wrong*)

With the "previous morning" we should include "the" and mostly a preposition isn't required but we could use "on" that is acceptable.

> I already had three cups of coffee (on) the previous morning.

3. I already had three cups of coffee last morning (*Wrong*)

**Last morning** might be understood but it isn't used in such context. The correct way to say this is **"yesterday morning"**.

You could use **"since"** for the *2nd* and *3rd* sentences:

- I already had three cups of coffee since the previous morning.
- I already had three cups of coffee since yesterday morning.

Comment: I've just corrected the last sentence, turned it into the past simple because the main point of the question is preposition usage. Duly noted, thank you

Comment: **last morning** sounds unnatural, probably because this morning has already passed, so last morning would be the same as this morning.. Most people would say **yesterday morning** to describe the morning of the previous day.

Comment: @JavaLatte Yeh, you are right.

Comment: "I've already had three coffees this morning" is neither unusual nor incorrect.

Comment: @Davo There's no plural of coffees when speaking of cups.. **coffees** means varieties of coffee. However, it will be understood.

Comment: I didn't use cups. *Go and bring us back six coffees: four black and two light and sweet* is perfectly normal usage. *Cups of coffee* is understood. Just like *I drank three sodas this weekend* doesn't imply that they were each a different flavor.

Comment: @Dave That's why I say that it will be understood but it's not a dictionary meaning. It's like saying, "I put two sugars in my cup".. Why *sugars* and why *in*?

Comment: @SovereignSun Coffee is a countable noun when meaning a serving of coffee see [wiktionary 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coffee#Noun).  Most people will not say "cups of coffee", even if it is perfectly understood.